# Why can this inner product condition be expressed as this sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, orthogonality, projection

I am studying a simple example of the projection theorem for Hilbert spaces.

Within a Hilbert space $H$ there is a subspace $U$ spanned by the vectors $u = (u_1, ..., u_k)^T$. So $U$ is just all the linear combinations $a^Tu$ with $a = (a_1, ..., a_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k$. The book says that, for an arbitrary $h \in H$, the projection of $h$ onto $U$ is the unique element $a_0^Tu$ that satisfies:

$\langle h - a_0^Tu, a^Tu \rangle = 0$ for all $a = (a_1, ..., a_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k$

I understand this to mean that if all the elements of $u$ are orthogonal to $h$, then the entire $U$ must also be orthogonal to $h$. But then it goes on to say that an equivalent condition is:

$\sum_{j=1}^k a_j\langle h - a_0^Tu, u_j \rangle = 0$ for all $a_j, j = 1,...,k$

**My question is, isn't it possible for some of the $\langle h - a_0^Tu, u_j \rangle$ to be positive and some negative, so that they cancel each other out and we end up with the sum being equal to zero, even though none of the $u_j$ are orthogonal to $h - a_0^Tu$?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner product is bilinear...

$$
\langle h-a_0^Tu, a^T u \rangle = \langle h-a_0^Tu, \sum_{i=1}^k a_i u_i \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \langle h-a_0^Tu, u_i \rangle
$$

Comment: This a solid algebra answer. If you have another minute, I would appreciate your input on the point that actually confuses me (see my comment under the answer by Kabo Murphy).

Comment: @AlvaroFuentes The point is that the equality must hold for *every* choice of $(a_1, \cdots, a_k)$.

Comment: I got it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}a_jb_j=0$ for all choices of $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ iff $b_j=0$ for all $j$. This can be proved by choosing (for any given $j$),  $a_i=0$ for $ i\neq j$ and $a_j=1$.

Comment: I'm sorry but with $k=2$, let's say that $a_1,a_2=1$ and $b_1=5,b_2=-5$. Then $a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 = 0$ even though $b_1,b_2 \neq 0$. It seems there is something very simple I'm not seeing...

Comment: @AlvaroFuentes Your example does not work because the equality must also hold for $a_1=1, a_2=0$ and $a_1=0, a_2=1$.